# Что такое python lite?

Tags: python

Мне сказали разобраться с каким-то python lite и сказать, чем он отличается от python 3. Я первый раз вообще слышу о python lite, да и в интернете инфы почти нет.

Answer (score 2):

Действительно, `Python lite` на просторах интернета не найти. Зато есть версия Питона `Python-light`, о которой упоминается [здесь (wiki.openwrt.org)](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/software/python) и [здесь (docs.onion.io)](https://docs.onion.io/omega2-docs/installing-and-using-python.html). Кажется, эта версия есть только для ОС *OpenWrt*.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что я написал неправильно?:) (Lite заместо Light)

Comment: Да: "мне сказали разобраться с каким-то python lite" – раз сказали, значит на слух, а `lite` и `light` звучат одинаково.